# Bypass Python IOError while disconnected from network?

Tags: python, ioerror

Hi there does any one know how can i pass thru IOError?
Basicly i have python script that is trying to scraping/getting data from my website
via urllib.
But when i am disconnected from network i got:

IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

How can i tell to python - keep trying until I will be connected?

```
for example:

currtokenurl = "http://www.example.com/heady"

f = urllib.urlopen(currtokenurl)
currtoken = f.read()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in a loop so that you can catch the error and retry. Many errors should not be retried, so create a list of the ones you like.

```
import time
import errno

retry_this = [errno.ETIMEOUT,]

currtokenurl = "http://www.example.com/heady"

while True:
    try:
        f = urllib.urlopen(currtokenurl)
        break
    except IOError, e:
        if e.errno in retry_this:
            time.sleep(10)
        else:
            raise
currtoken = f.read()
```

It could be that the remote end is not connected, so you may want a way to limit this while loop and give up completely.

Comment: Thanks guys! Tried both and works great! Btw where can i get list of errors so i can determinate witch one i would need to retry?

Comment: `import errno;dir(errno)` gives you a list. then search the net. you'll find a couple of pages with most of them. btw, you see standard linux codes and windows codes (they start w/ WSA). if you are on windows, google them both.

Answer (score 0):

Use `try/except` to trap the IOError:

```
import urllib
import time

def read_page(url):
  try:
    f = urllib.urlopen(url)
    return f.read()
  except IOError as e:
    return None

while True:
  f = read_page("http://www.example.com/heady")
  if f is None:
    print "reading again"
    time.sleep(5)  # try again in 5 seconds
  else:
    break
```